# Bitcoind information about the input and output

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node, nodes

Im trying to get the wallets/accounts the money got sent to. But `getrawtransaction` does not give any information about the reciever or sender

Answer (score 1):

I copied transaction id of a random transaction from block explorer: [`c04878631aa447edf47087aa9583a0e1113f6e4bba12d33f3610ce0242c72855`](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/c04878631aa447edf47087aa9583a0e1113f6e4bba12d33f3610ce0242c72855)

Run below command in Bitcoin Core:

```
getrawtransaction c04878631aa447edf47087aa9583a0e1113f6e4bba12d33f3610ce0242c72855 true
```

It returns below information for this transaction:

```
{
  "txid": "c04878631aa447edf47087aa9583a0e1113f6e4bba12d33f3610ce0242c72855",
  "hash": "48b1453c2a13b6c0f2ceb12cfbd1d480b8b44a73a573a6b1f8d0358970d115c9",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 223,
  "vsize": 142,
  "weight": 565,
  "locktime": 1974680,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "368b61bde14aed5d2c1182da74e0939676bc739fc8049f459f981e6881835c9b",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "",
        "hex": ""
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "3044022013f53082a5446625195113f435209526d3012015aeceefecdafc829fffb6fcfe02201a22da1902570f1756b11065b3fc39263559a4dd12ad30b9a4bf3effa904d5e601",
        "029fc0881c0bee9c3b0035ae849aa0489ffd6520d0334a6cf2698615f71f25fea2"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967294
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00010000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 c6953606f7d751d8c1a956c888ce96ed97d7e09b OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a914c6953606f7d751d8c1a956c888ce96ed97d7e09b87",
        "address": "2NBMEXdaTcnYFzRKmNWrZqxAjFFqe5Shjwd",
        "type": "scripthash"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.01050127,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 c058152cf8e0a38b9ce4dee43b902a0e53b50e2c",
        "hex": "0014c058152cf8e0a38b9ce4dee43b902a0e53b50e2c",
        "address": "tb1qcpvp2t8cuz3ch88ymmjrhyp2pefm2r3vawuafw",
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
      }
    }
  ],
  "hex": "020000000001019b5c8381681e989f459f04c89f73bc769693e074da82112c5ded4ae1bd618b360000000000feffffff02102700000000000017a914c6953606f7d751d8c1a956c888ce96ed97d7e09b870f06100000000000160014c058152cf8e0a38b9ce4dee43b902a0e53b50e2c02473044022013f53082a5446625195113f4352
```

If you are looking for inputs and outputs in the results:

**Output(s):**

```
"vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00010000,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 c6953606f7d751d8c1a956c888ce96ed97d7e09b OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a914c6953606f7d751d8c1a956c888ce96ed97d7e09b87",
        "address": "2NBMEXdaTcnYFzRKmNWrZqxAjFFqe5Shjwd",
        "type": "scripthash"
      }
    },
    {
      "value": 0.01050127,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 c058152cf8e0a38b9ce4dee43b902a0e53b50e2c",
        "hex": "0014c058152cf8e0a38b9ce4dee43b902a0e53b50e2c",
        "address": "tb1qcpvp2t8cuz3ch88ymmjrhyp2pefm2r3vawuafw",
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
      }
    }
  ]
```

**Input(s):**

```
"vin": [
    {
      "txid": "368b61bde14aed5d2c1182da74e0939676bc739fc8049f459f981e6881835c9b",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "",
        "hex": ""
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "3044022013f53082a5446625195113f435209526d3012015aeceefecdafc829fffb6fcfe02201a22da1902570f1756b11065b3fc39263559a4dd12ad30b9a4bf3effa904d5e601",
        "029fc0881c0bee9c3b0035ae849aa0489ffd6520d0334a6cf2698615f71f25fea2"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967294
    }
  ]
```

The important part here is transaction `id` and `vout` number for input(s). In this case we have only one input but there can be more. To get more information about this input you can run the below command:

```
getrawtransaction 368b61bde14aed5d2c1182da74e0939676bc739fc8049f459f981e6881835c9b true
```

And check `vout:0` which is:

```
{
      "value": 0.01060269,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 ba9cfe15c989f7c3ef012f2bec8287ebc00b5bf9",
        "hex": "0014ba9cfe15c989f7c3ef012f2bec8287ebc00b5bf9",
        "address": "tb1qh2w0u9wf38mu8mcp9u47eq58a0qqkklel40v48",
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
      }
    }
```

| Input(s) | Output(s) |
| --- | --- |
| tb1qh2w0u9wf38mu8mcp9u47eq58a0qqkklel40v48 (0.01060269) | 2NBMEXdaTcnYFzRKmNWrZqxAjFFqe5Shjwd (0.00010000) |
|  | tb1qcpvp2t8cuz3ch88ymmjrhyp2pefm2r3vawuafw (0.01050127) |

`getrawtransaction` can be used for any Bitcoin transaction if `-txindex` is enabled.

You can use [`gettransaction`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/gettransaction/) for wallet transactions